# Consul/Nomad combo - How the consul healthcheck resolves its host IP

Tags: consul, nomad

I have a setup with nomad and consul on my machine.
I start a service with a nomad job and have it registered successfully.
My issue is on IP resolutions:
- in Nomad UI, I can see the IP **10.0.75.1**
- in Consul UI, in service discovery, I can see the IP **10.0.75.1**
- in consul healthcheck, the IP used is a different one **172.31.194.209**

Both IP are good host IPs, but my problem is the service only answer on **10.0.75.1**.

My point is not really trying to have that service working as I could workaround the issue by putting a different configuration for it to answer on **171.31.194.209** too.

What I'd like is to understand is **how the consul healthcheck resolves its host IP** and in my case to a different one than the Nomad/Consul-UIs. Also a way to force that resolution would be great.

Note that the Healthcheck is setup by Nomad with **network_mode = host**

**Some configurations:**
**CONSUL**

```
{
  "ui":  true,
  "data_dir":  "C:\\Users\\foo\\consul\\data",
  "client_addr":  "10.0.75.1",
  "node_name":  "foonode",
  "server":  true,
  "bind_addr":  "10.0.75.1",
  "ports":  {
              "http":  8500
          },
  "bootstrap":  true,
  "bootstrap_expect":  1,
  "datacenter":  "local",
  "node_meta":  {
                  "user":  "foo"
              }
}
```

**NOMAD**

```
name = "foonode"
bind_addr = "10.0.75.1"
datacenter = "local"
data_dir = "C:\\Users\\foo\\nomad\\data"
server {
    enabled = true
    bootstrap_expect = 1
}
client {
    enabled = true
    options {
        "driver.raw_exec.enable" = "1"
    }
    meta {
        user = "foo"
    }
}
consul {
    address = "http://10.0.75.1:8500"
}
```

Comment: Consul uses the IP address assigned to that container by Docker, you'll find it in the environment of your running container in the `NOMAD_IP_foo` variable, where `foo` is the name you assigned to the port of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but your machine has multiple ip addresses. One of them is the 171 address.  Would an "advertise_addr": "10.0.75.1" added to your consul.json configuration help?